# I have an F1 US student Visa. Will I get in trouble visiting Iraqi Kurdistan when I come back to the US?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, iraq, iraqi-kurdistan

Question says it all. I am from Europe but I go to school in the US. I graduate this year and I thought about visiting Iraqi Kurdistan this year, before I graduate. My question is, will I get in trouble when coming back to the US because I have been to Iraq? Is there a chance I can't go back in? I am aware that I will not be able to apply for the ESTA again, but since I already have my visa, will they get me in trouble? Will they even know if they don't check the stamp in my passport? 
Thank you very much for your help.